# writing unicode text in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

when I try to write an Arabic language words in xcode editor it does not display correctly, it's displayed as messed up words and reversed (the output in iPhone is OK), so it becomes harder for me to review the strings I entered in the editor, is there anyway to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I think those are bugs in Xcode (you can try changing the font, but I don't think the direction can be changed).

However, it is generally preferable to write your strings in English and then use internationalization (i18n) techniques to convert and display them in Arabic at runtime. A quick google revealed this [blogpost](http://rudifa.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/i18n-of-my-iphone-app/). This solves two issues:

1. You can support any number of languages.
2. You can store your Arabic text in a separate file and edit it with an external editor, making it easier to work with.

Comment: i changed the font without any effect